# Next.js — router.push scrolls page to the top despite scroll option set to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, react-select

I am using Next.js' built-in internationalisation features to  change my app's language and everything is working perfectly except for one undesirable behaviour:

Calling the `changeLanguage` function results in the page scrolling to the top **in spite of setting the router's scroll option to false**.

*Please note that [Next.js - router.push without scrolling to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902664/next-js-router-push-without-scrolling-to-the-top) and [Next.js maintain scroll position when page Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606737/next-js-maintain-scroll-position-when-page-routing) did not solve my issue.*

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const LanguageToggler = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  const { locale, pathname, locales, asPath } = router;

  const changeLanguage = (e) => {
    const locale = e.value; // is equal to one of these values: ['en', 'sv', 'ru', 'fr']
    router.push(pathname, asPath, { locale }, { scroll: false });
  };

 return (
      <Select
        ...irrelevant
        onChange={changeLanguage}
        components={{
          Option: CustomSelectOption,
        }}
      />
    )
};

export default LanguageToggler;
```

P.S. The react-select library is used to display a dropdown list of flags, clicking each flag summons `changeLanguage` to update the locale accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) accepts three parameters.

```js
router.push(pathname, asPath, { locale }, { scroll: false });
```

should be

```js
import router from 'next/router';

router.push(pathname, asPath, { locale, scroll: false });
```

Comment: doesn't work either, nextjs 13.4 , tried both <Link> and via onClick router.push

Comment: You must make sure that the answers you use are for your use of Next. There are multiple routers now and this is clearly linked to pages directory docs which still functions as answered.